# Regex - nested patterns - within outer pattern but exclude inner pattern

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep, pattern-matching

I have a file with the content below.

```
<td> ${ dontReplaceMe } ReplaceMe ${dontReplaceMeEither} </td>
```

I want to match 'ReplaceMe' if it is in the td tag, but NOT if it is in the ${ ... } expression.

Can I do this with regex?

Currently have:

```bsh
sed '/\${.*?ReplaceMe.*?}/!s/ReplaceMe/REPLACED/g' data.txt
```

Comment: Any particular language?

Comment: I updated the tags. To answer your question though: bash scripting

Comment: Steve - you should update your original question instead of asking the same thing again (even if it is worded slightly differently). Thanks.

Comment: Steve, I updated my answer with a pattern that works for the four most trivial cases. I highly discourage you from using it though!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**This is not possible.**

Regex can be used for **Type-3 Chomsky languages** (regular language).
Your sample code however is a **Type-2 Chomsky language** (context-free language).

Pretty much as soon as any kind of nesting (brackets) is involved you're dealing with context free languages, which are not covered by regular expressions.

**There is** basically **no way** to define `within a pair of x and y` **in a regular expression**, as this would **require the regular expression to have some kind of stack, which it doesn't** (being functionally equivalent to a finite state automaton).

---

**Challenged by brandizzi to find a regex that might match at least trivial cases**
I actually came up with this (painfully hacky) regex pattern:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=<td>)((?:(?:\{.*?\})*[^{]*?)*)(ReplaceMe)(.*)(?=<\/td>)/$1REPLACED$3/g'
```

It **does proper** *(sic!)* **matching** for these cases:

```
<td> ${ dontReplaceMe } ReplaceMe ${dontReplaceMeEither} </td>
<td> ReplaceMe ${dontReplaceMeEither} </td>
<td> ${ dontReplaceMe } ReplaceMe </td>
<td> ReplaceMe </td>
```

And **fails with this one** *(nesting is Chomsky Type-2, remember? ;) )*:

```
<td>${ ${ dontReplaceMe } ReplaceMe ${dontReplaceMeEither} }</td>
```

And it **can't replace multiple matches** either:

```
<td> ReplaceMe ReplaceMe </td>
<td> ReplaceMe ${dontReplaceMeEither} ReplaceMe </td>
```

Getting the leading `$` covered was the tricky part.
This and keeping [Reginald](http://atastypixel.com/blog/reginald-regex-explorer/)/[Reggy](http://reggyapp.com/) from crashing constantly while writing this beast.

### AGAIN: EXPERIMENTAL, DO NOT EVER USE THIS IN PRODUCTION CODE!

<sup>(…or I'll hunt you down, should I ever have to work with your code/app ;)</sup>

Comment: you are right Some points to be considered in your answer. 1. If the text to be marked up is pretty simple then it can be practical to match  it with regex, but I know you know it :) 2. Some regexes are recursive and can match context-free grammars (eg http://tinyurl.com/3jb2xqh
). 3. Although regexes does not match context-free languages, sed can match it. Actually, I think sed is even Turing-complete since it supports concatenation and looping. I do not believe it would be very practical but it looks possible. Anyway, your answer is correct and important.

Comment: Steve asked "Can I do this with regex?", to which the answer remains "no" ;) You made an interesting point about sed though. Wasn't aware of this, thanks! :) Regarding regex being capable of (unsafely) matching simple cases here: See my updates answer. ;) I feel dirty now. Sorry, Noam :(

Comment: Don't worry, I won't be using anything that looks that hacky in production.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for such simple case, you just need to verify that the line *does not match* `${.*}`:

```
$ sed '/\${.*}/!s/ReplaceMe/REPLACED/' input
<td> REPLACED </td>
<td> ${ don't ReplaceMe } </td>
```

The `!` after the `/\${.*}/` sed address negates the criteria.

OTOH, if the case is not that so simple, I'd suspect that your problem will grow a lot and regex will not be the best solution.

Comment: Is there a grep equivalent for does not match? I want to use grep to generate a list of files for sed to loop through.

Comment: @steve, thats what sed does, you can pass multiple files to sed. perhaps sed 's/MATCHTEXT/REPLACEDTEXT/g' *.html will loop through all .html files. Is this not appropriate?

Comment: @Steve yes, there it is, it is the `-v` option of grep. You can use it this way: `ls | grep -v 'PATTERN'` Only files that does not match are listed. If you want to apply sed to them, can use just `sed -i.bkp 's/foo/bar/g' $(grep -v 'PATTERN')`.

Comment: @matchew I am not sure but I think he wants to apply sed only for some files whose name does not match some pattern. Well, I'd recommend @Steve to ask another question about it if our comments did not helped him :)

Comment: I asked another question at Q:6272754.  I'm working off brandizzi's sed command and he might be right that my problem is a lot more complexicated. @matchew, thanks. Eventually I need to make my sed recursive (seding files within folder1/folder2/data.txt). I'm hoping seed can do this.

Comment: @Steve combing find+sed you can recursively move through dirs

Comment: Matching of nested structures with Regex is *not* possible. **Never ever rely on regex for matching type-<3 languages structures** (which this question clearly is a member of).

Answer (score 1):

usually it is a bad idea to use regex when there is structured markup involved. in some special cases it might be ok, but there are better tools to parse html and *then* you can use regex on the text nodes.

Comment: Could you specify some of those tools that might help with embedded expressions in HTML?  I can't find them or don't know what they're called.

Comment: i would suggest any tool that can parse a dom tree. for example XML::DOM::Parser for perl and xml.dom.minidom.parse for python. then apply a simpler regex to the textnodes inside the dom elements you want and forget about the <td>s.

Answer (score 0):

Something like `<td>.*(?<!${).*ReplaceMe(?!.*}).*</td>` should work, if grep supports negative lookbehinds (I don't remember if it does).

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i 's/<td>\sReplaceMe\s<\/td>/<td>Replaced<\/td>/gi' input.file
```

worked for me.

you may consider using -i.bak to backup the old file, in case of a mistake.

alternatively,

`perl -pi -e 's/<td>\sReplaceMe\s<\/td>/<td>Replaced<\/td>/g' temp`

also works, again, note the -pi.bak to backup.