# Regex - replace if not in brackets

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep, pattern-matching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex - nested patterns - within outer pattern but exclude inner pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271304/regex-nested-patterns-within-outer-pattern-but-exclude-inner-pattern)

This is a similar question to question [6271304](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271304/regex-nested-patterns-within-outer-pattern-but-exclude-inner-pattern) but I didn't get an answer that worked for me.  I re-arranged the question to better target the problem.

If I have the following content in a file: how do I replace 'ReplaceMe' if it is in a td tag but NOT if it is in ${ ... }

```
<td> ${ dontReplaceMe } ReplaceMe ${dontReplaceMeEither} </td>
```

Here is what I have so far but it seems to replace everything (even the negated criteria):

```sh
 sed '/\${.*?ReplaceMe.*?}/!s/ReplaceMe/REPLACED/g' data.txt
```