# how to check if in parenthesis in regex

Tags: regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex - nested patterns - within outer pattern but exclude inner pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271304/regex-nested-patterns-within-outer-pattern-but-exclude-inner-pattern)

I am trying to get a substring of a string after/from a word. But I want that word to be outside of the parenthesis. For example:

`something (theword other things) theword some more stuff` should give me `theword some more stuff` instead of `theword other things) theword more stuff`. How can I do this in regular expressions. I am using PCRE (e.g. php, python regex engine)

Edit:

The string I am trying to use this regular expression on is a mysql statement. I am trying to remove parts until FROM part, but inner sql statements (that are in parenthesis causing problems to me).

Comment: Would `foo\(bar\)baz` count as parentheses or just `foo(bar)baz`?

Comment: I am certain that my parenthesis won't be escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a task similar to the one described in this question: [Regex - nested patterns - within outer pattern but exclude inner pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271304/regex-nested-patterns-within-outer-pattern-but-exclude-inner-pattern/6272941#6272941)

See my answer for why it's not 100% possible and for a hack-ish solution that works most of the times (for shallow nesting, that is).

Update:

If you know that parentheses wil neither be nested, nor escaped, you could use something akin to this:

```
(?<=\)|^)([^()]+)(?=\(|$)
```

So with this as the haystack:

```
something (theword other things) theword (some) more stuff
```

Wou would end up with these snippets in capture group 1:

```
something 
 theword 
 more stuff
```

Note that there are leading/trailing spaces captured as well, to prevent them use this instead:

```
(?<=\)|^)\s*([^()]+)\s*(?=\(|$)
```

Same regex pattern, but with comments:

```
(?<=\)|^) #either ")" or beginning of string
\s* #optional leading whitespace
([^()]+) #any sequence of characters but "(" or ")"
\s* #optional trailing whitespace
(?=\(|$) #either "(" or end of string
```

Comment: I am sure that my pattern won't use nested parenthesis. I have edited my first post.

Comment: Nested parens are not a problem.  You’re just doing it wrong.

Comment: @tchrist: would love to see a better solution, mind posting one?

Comment: The standard pattern for matching nested parens in the *pcrepattern* manpage is `( \( ( [^()]++ | (?1) )* \) )` although I tend to use `( \( (?: [^()]++ | (?-1) )*+ \) )` from the *perlre* manpage (v5.10 or better) with recursing on relative group `-1` instead of on absolute group `1` so that I don’t have to renumber. Better yet, forget about numbered groups by using a named group `paren` via `(?<paren> \( (?: [^()]++ | (?&paren) )*+ \) )`. Those are all in `/x` mode ᴀᴋᴀ `"(?x)"` or `PCRE_EXTENDED`, becauseihatereadingstuffruntgetherlikethis.